# How to stop loop if the condition met inside foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, foreach

i tried to make the loop stop and only print 1 content inside their if, if the condition have been met but it always either print the condition more than one, have both condition printed, or the else statement doesn't display anything. Any suggestion?

```
$tf = 'belom';
$tf2 = 'belom';
if ($tf == 'belom') {
               foreach ($roles as $role) {
                    if (in_array("user", $role) && $tf == 'belom') {
                         print_r($role);
                         $tf = 'udah';
                         echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Primary</button>';
                         $tf2 = 'udah';
                    }elseif ($tf2 !== 'udah') {

                         echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Primary</button>';
                         $tf2 = 'udah';
                    }
               }
          } 
     // }
```

Sorry for the grammar, i'm not really good with english.
Hope you guys understand.

Comment: What do you mean, you _"tried to make the loop stop"_? To leave a loop before it is finished, you need to use the `break;` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Use [break](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) to end the execution of the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) for `break` keyword. You can use as below.

```
$tf = 'belom';
$tf2 = 'belom';
if ($tf == 'belom') 
{
   foreach ($roles as $role) 
   {
     if (in_array("user", $role) && $tf == 'belom') 
     {
        print_r($role);
        $tf = 'udah';
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Primary</button>';
        $tf2 = 'udah';
        break; // USE THIS KEYWORD TO BREAK OUT FROM THE LOOP
     }
     elseif ($tf2 !== 'udah') 
     {
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Primary</button>';
        $tf2 = 'udah';
        break; // USE THIS KEYWORD TO BREAK OUT FROM THE LOOP
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $value){
 if($value === 'stop looping entirely'){
  break;
 }
 else if($value === 'skip the current iteration'){
  continue;
 }
}
?>
```